# Getting error in Adjust library, Integrated with Pods

Tags: objective-c, ios8, cocoapods

I am getting this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-Adjust
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I added this to my Podfile:

```
pod 'Adjust', :git => 'git://github.com/adjust/ios_sdk.git', :tag => 'v4.2.5'
```

I have installed pods successfully, but still get the above error.

Comment: Made intent more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running `pod install`, make sure that you are opening the `.xcworkspace` instead of the `.xcproject` in Xcode to be able to build and use Pods in your project.